# Why it changes the value of the variables?

Tags: c, linux

I have this code. Screen show twice the value of variables and is different. Why? Am I doing something wrong?
Linux compiled with gcc.
I dont understand the error. The value should not change in the function.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int fd;
    struct ifreq ifr;
    char *iface = "eth0";
    unsigned char *mac, *ip, *mask, *broad;

    fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    ifr.ifr_addr.sa_family = AF_INET;
    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name , iface , IFNAMSIZ-1);

    //get the ip address
    ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifr);
    ip= (unsigned char *)inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&ifr.ifr_addr )->sin_addr);
    //display ip
    printf("IP address of %s - %s\n" , iface , ip );
    //get the netmask ip
        ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFNETMASK, &ifr);
    mask = (unsigned char *)inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&ifr.ifr_addr )->sin_addr);
    //display netmask
    printf("Netmask of %s - %s\n" , iface , mask);
        //get the MAC address
    ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &ifr);
    mac = (unsigned char *)ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data;
    //display mac address
    printf("Mac of %s - %.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x\n" , iface, mac[0], mac[1], mac[2], mac[3], mac[4], mac[5]);
    //get the BroadCast ip
        ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFBRDADDR, &ifr);
    broad = (unsigned char *)inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&ifr.ifr_addr )->sin_addr);
    //display BroadCast
        printf("Broadcast of %s - %s\n" , iface , broad);

    close(fd);

    //display ip
    printf("IP address of %s - %s\n" , iface , ip );
    //display netmask
    printf("Netmask of %s - %s\n" , iface , mask);
    //display mac address
    printf("Mac of %s - %.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x\n" ,iface, mac[0], mac[1], mac[2], mac[3], mac[4], mac[5]);
    //display BroadCast
        printf("Broadcast of %s - %s\n" , iface , broad);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why `unsigned char *`, it's not the problem but why? I am having a hard time reading the code, could you format it correctly? And I don't understand which value is changing where!

Comment: Just, asking, did you enable all the warnings for your compiler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each call to `ioctl` overwrites the contents in `ifr`.

`ip` is just a pointer into the `ifr` structure. When you print `ip` you print the address obtained from the last call to `ioctl`.

You can solve your problem either by using different `struct ifreq` in your calls or by copying the data you want to preserve to another memory area (for example with `strdup`).

Comment: Or printing the required data right after the `ioctl()` call.